# Animation in blender: How to link restrict visibility with restrict viewport rendering

Tags: animation, scripting

I have created an assembly sequence and the viewport visibility of the components have been restricted along the animation. BUT I forgot to retrict the viewport visibility as well :(

Now I would like to link the viewport visibility with the viewport rendering only without affecting the rest of my animation. Is there any way to do this?

This script in the console doesn't create link: 
"for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects: ob.hide_render = ob.hide" ; is there a script that would enable this?

[image: outliner with forgotten restrict rendering]

Comment: thanks Nicola Sap , exactly what I need :)